# finding text in ajax returns on Javascript console

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, console, firebug

My javascript framework uses Ajax to dynamically change certain parts of my page. When I use a javascript console like firebug or the one that comes with Chrome and I try to find some tags it seems that the dynamically altered HTML parts are not searched. I will have to hunt them down manually which is a daunting task at times since the framework generates tons of HTML.

The only info I can find about this concerns finding tags programmatically by traversing the DOM but that is not what I'm looking for, I need my debugger to be able to find those tags when I am examining the code at runtime.

Is there a way around this in any browser?

---

I've created a simple example to demonstrate [here](http://www.softwear.nl/test/ajax.html)

If you open it with Chrome, start the javascript console before clicking on the button and search for the word **tag** you will find 1 in the original HTML.
Next, click the button. You will see the  change. Now search again for the same word **tag**. It will not be found. However, if you do a find for **ta**, it will be found. Looks like the search results are buffered someway and not cleared once the page changes.

Firebug doesn't seem to update the page at all.

---

I found out that if you start Chrome's javascript console after the Ajax refresh, text can be found however, if the Ajax refresh happens when the Javascript console is allready open, searching capabilities within the refreshed Ajax content is limited. I still can't figure out when it does/doesn't work.

Comment: Are you looking for the new elements in the Elements tab or are you querying for them in the console's command line?

Comment: I'm using the find box in the upper righthand corner of either Chrome's javascript console or FireBug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug > HTML Panel > mini-menu > Expand Changes
Then your search will work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are appending the ajax content to the document, at least some hidden div. It would be useful if you provide an example.

Comment: ***HOW*** are you searching for the word tag?

Comment: I type it in the search box in the upper righthand corner when Chrome Javascript-console is open. Works the same in FireBug.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery expressions in the console if you want to find something particular. Something like that: $('#myid'). Of course, you can search not only by id using jquery.